# Почему не работает move_uploaded_file

Tags: php, html, css, sql, веб-программирование

Почему-то не работает данная строка:

```
$moving = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['stage_image']['tmp_name'], 'media/Images/' . $_FILES['stage_image']['name']);
```

Искал везде, где можно: Habr, stackoverflow, overcoad и т.д. Увы ничего не помогло. И заранее, да у меня точно есть папка с таким именем.

Comment: полный путь от корня диска указывай, может там прав на запись нет, может ты банально слеш перед media пропустил, и не пашет из-за этого

Comment: @Jean-Claude, Оба варианта не помогают. Второй потому, что папка media находится в той же директории, что и скрипт.

Comment: отладчик поставь

Comment: Читаем документацию: Если from не является загруженным файлом, никаких действий не предпринимается и move_uploaded_file() возвращает false.
Если from является загруженным файлом, но не может быть перемещён по каким-либо причинам, никаких действий не предпринимается и move_uploaded_file() возвращает false. Кроме того, отображается предупреждение. Но мы, конечно, умные и выключили вывод предупреждений, а так же выключили запись предупреждений в лог. Да мы принципиально лог не смотрим, а зачем нам знать причину ошибки

Comment: полно рекомендаций и ответов https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501749/php-move-uploaded-file-error